# Read a Struct JSON with AWS Glue that is on a single line

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I have this JSON on a Bucket that has been crawled with a classifier that splits arrays into record with this JSON classifier `$[*]`.

I noticed that the JSON is on a single line - nothing wrong with syntax - but this results in the table being created having a single column of type array containing a struct which contains the actual fields I need.

In Athena I wasn't able to access the data and Glue was not able to read the columns as in array.field; so I manually changed the structure of the table making a single struct type with the other fields inside. This I'm able to query on Athena and get the Glue wizard to recognise the single columns as part of the struct.

When I create the job and map the fields accordingly (this is what is automatically generated, note the `array.field` notation `applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("array.col1", "long", "col1", "long"), ("array.col2", "string", "col2", "string"), ("array.col3", "string", "col3", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")`) I test the output on a table in an S3 Bucket. The Job does not fail at all, BUT creates files in the Bucket that are empty!

Another thing I've tried is to modify the Source JSON and add return lines:

this is before:

```
[{"col1":322,"col2":299,"col3":1613552400000,"col4":"TEST","col5":"TEST"},{"col1":2,"col2":0,"col3":1613552400000,"col4":"TEST","col5":"TEST"}]
```

this is after:

```
[
{"col1":322,"col2":299,"col3":1613552400000,"col4":"TEST","col5":"TEST"},
{"col1":2,"col2":0,"col3":1613552400000,"col4":"TEST","col5":"TEST"}
]
```

Having the file modified as stated before lets me correctly read and write data; this led me to believe that the problem is having a bad JSON at the beginning. Before asking to change the JSON is there something I can implement in my Glue Job (Spark 2.4, Python 3) to handle a JSON on a single line? I've searched everywhere but found nothing.

The end goal is to load data into Redshift, we're working S3 to S3 to check on why data isn't being read.

Thanks in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: `df = spark.read.json(path)` gives correct schema (not single array column) with the example in your question.

Comment: @blackbishop, `path` would be the S3 Bucket path, right?

Comment: a path to the a json file containing the single line you provided above.